# Copying Utility in c (like cp in *NIX), unable to copy mp4 or mp3 files

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am trying to make a copying utility in C just like `cp` in *NIX, by using pipes.

The code works fine for txt files but when I copy mp4 or mp3 files they get corrupted. 
For mp4 files I get `No video or audio selected` and for mp3 I get `Failed to recognize file format`.

I am allocating 250 bytes of buffer and reading and writing 250 bytes to and from the pipe respectively to the files (source and destination files). The path to the files is assumed to be given via command line arguments.

If I read and write the complete size of the file to be copied, from and to the pipe the code works fine. But it is not working when I am using a buffer of 250 bytes.

I can't allocate the the size of the file to `buff` and `childbuff` because then I won't be able to copy files having size greater than my RAM, i.e, 8GB.

Any help appreciated.

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
 #include <unistd.h> 
 #include <stdlib.h> 
 #include <sys/types.h> 
 #include <fcntl.h> 
 #include <string.h> 
 #include <sys/stat.h>

 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int fildes[2];
    char ch;
    int bytes, target, handle;
    pid_t cpid;
    int sz = 0;
    struct stat st;
    stat(argv[1], & st);
    sz = st.st_size;

    char * buff = malloc(250);
    char * childbuff = malloc(250);
    pipe(fildes);
    if (argc != 3) {
      printf("Command needs two arguments");
      exit(1);
    }

    if (access(argv[1], F_OK) == -1) {
      printf("File %s , not found", argv[1]);
      exit(0);
    }
    if (access(argv[2], F_OK) != -1) {
      printf("File already exists, Do you want to overwrite ? [y,n]");
      scanf("%c", & ch);
      if (ch == 'n') {
        exit(0);
      }
      FILE * fil = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
      fclose(fil);
    }

    int tmp = 250, tmp1 = 250, wr = 0, rr = 0;

    cpid = fork();

    if (cpid == -1) {
      perror("fork");
      exit(1);
    }

    if (cpid == 0) {
      FILE * ptr = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
      while (rr < sz) {
        if (sz - rr < 250)
          tmp1 = sz - rr;
        else
          tmp1 = 250;

        rr = rr + tmp1;

        close(fildes[1]);
        read(fildes[0], childbuff, tmp1);
        close(fildes[0]);

        fwrite(childbuff, 1, tmp1, ptr);

      }
      fclose(ptr);

    } else {
      FILE * ptr = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
      while (wr < sz) {
        if (sz - wr < 250)
          tmp = sz - wr;
        else
          tmp = 250;

        wr = wr + tmp;

        close(fildes[0]);
        bytes = fread(buff, 1, tmp, ptr);
        write(fildes[1], buff, bytes);
      }
      fclose(ptr);

    }
  }
```

Comment: please use something like https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier# next time to format your code, otherwise it's hard to read

Comment: is the size of input and output files different?

Comment: No, i am trying to mirror cp command in *NIX you give it a path to the source file and the destination file and it copies the source to the destination. So the size of both of them is the same. More accurately the size of the destination does not matter what matters is the size of the source which has to be copied.

Comment: but after you actually run the program, is the output file size __really__ the same?

Comment: This lines look suspicious `read(fildes[0], childbuff, tmp1); close(fildes[0]);` why do you close the pipe immediately after reading one buffer from it?

Comment: Yes i checked that, it is indeed same. But the destination file does not run properly.

Comment: @Devstr is right. after the first loop, `read()` can't really read from the pipe anymore and there are only some aribtrary bytes written to the dest file (probably the first bytes again)

Comment: Ya, removing **close(fildes[0]);** did the trick. Do you mind explaining why it worked?

Comment: yep, and since result of `read` is not checked you are oblivious to any possible error reported.

Comment: yeah, let me write up a proper answer

Comment: You are making this much more complicated than it needs to be with the pipes and the forking and the mixing fread/fwrite with read/write.  The bug is probably somewhere in all that mess, but even if it worked correctly it would be slower than a simple loop doing read and then write from file A to file B.

Comment: Also the code does not work for mkv file formats it gives **Failed to recognize File format** error.

Comment: @zwol It's a uni assignment i have to use pipes.

Comment: If that code works or not has nothing to do with the file format. Whenever the file is bigger than one portion you read (250 bytes) the parent process won't read the data because of the `close()`

Comment: @Ingo Leonhardt , Thanks, you are right int sz, was too big for the file i was copying. Everything works as a charm.

Comment: Please **do not** use https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier . It destroys `#include` directives. OP: The code in the question should match the code you're actually compiling. If you reformat it, compile the reformatted version before copying it into the question. (I just corrected the `#include` directives.)

Comment: I've informed the folks at codebeautify.org of the problem.

Comment: @Devstr: I forgot to tag you on my previous comment. https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier is broken.

Comment: Thank you for reporting it. It was the first result in Google and I noticed that it breaks includes. I hoped that people are mindful enough to look at the result before copy pasting it. Alas.

Answer (score 2):

Two obvious problems

- you don't check the return values of the `read` and `write` calls, so you don't know how much data was actually read or written (which might be less than requested)
- you close the read file descriptor the first time through the loop, so on the second and subsequent iterations, it will be closed and the read will fail.  You don't notice as you're not checking the return value of read...

moral - **ALWAYS** check the return values of your calls.